# JQuery isn't working in Code Pen (Safari or Chrome)

Tags: jquery, codepen

I'm working through Free Code Camp and I am making a tribute page for Violeta Parra. I've added the jQuery and jQuery UI plugins in settings and I've copied some stuff straight from the FCC lessons but it don't seem to be working. Here is the pen:

https://codepen.io/enheduana/pen/NYLMZN

So in the HTML section the id for the Wikipedia link is "shake":

```
<p style="font-size:30px">You can learn more about Violeta Para on <a 
href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violeta_Parra" 
id="shake">Wikipedia</a></p>
```

and in the Javascript section I have given that id the class "animated shake"(*edited with camelcase*):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#shake").addClass("animated shake");
});
```

However, when I look at my page the Wikipedia link doesn't shake. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `addClass` not `addclass`

Comment: I was troubleshooting with that and forgot to change it back. It still doesn't seem to work even in camelcase.

Comment: I've had this issue before on safari, that was because the DOM was not repainting when adding or removing classes. It also didn't matter if it was plain javascript or jQuery. Then I fixed it by doing $(tabContent).hide().show(0); after every class toggle. That seemed to repaint the DOM. However in the current iOs version (11.3.1), nothing works anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your function call to `addClass` needs to be camelcase. It's `addClass` not `addclass`.

Edit: Also, why don't you just apply the class on the element in the HTML? Why does it have to be applied via jQuery?

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Don't bother answering typo only questions as they have no value to anyone other than the OP. Instead, vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo, as that close reason was created explicitly for questions where a typo is the problem.

Comment: @j08691 will do

Comment: Oh I was just rouble shooting that. It still doesn't work even in camelcase.

Comment: Also I'm just trying to use the things I have learned in FCC. I'm not sure how to add them directly to the HTML element, but I would like to be able to apply my jQuery knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a class definition for `shake` or `animated` in your CSS. Jquery adds the classes as supposed to, but they don't do anything because they aren't defined. Just add the definitions and it should work fine.